# useInfiniteQuery: invalidar y hacer refetch tiene un comportamiento extraño

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy implementando una lista infinita de elementos para el usuario con React-Query (v3), y cuando el usuario elimina uno, quiero volver a obtener todos las páginas, pero no está funcionando. Permíteme explicártelo después de mostrar algo de código

```
function useUserWatchlist({
  userId,
  pageNumber = 1,
  pageSize = 24,
  queryOptions,
}) {

  const userList = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['watchlist', userId],
    async ({ pageParam = pageNumber }) => await fetchUserWatchlist(userId, pageParam, pageSize),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
        let nextPage = null;

        if (lastPage.pagination.pageNumber < lastPage.pagination.totalPages) {
          nextPage = lastPage.pagination.pageNumber + 1;
        }

        return nextPage;
      },
      getPreviousPageParam: (firstPage) => {
        let previousPage = null;

        if (firstPage.pagination.pageNumber > 0) {
          previousPage = firstPage.pagination.pageNumber - 1;
        }

        return previousPage;
      },
      ...queryOptions,
    }
  );

    const {
data,
isLoading,
isError,
error,
isSuccess,
hasNextPage,
hasPreviousPage,
isRefetching,
isFetchingNextPage,
fetchNextPage,
fetchPreviousPage,
refetch,


} = userList;

  let watchlistResultsDTO = {};

  if (!isLoading && !isError) {
    watchlistResultsDTO = {
      pageData: data?.pages.map((page, index) => {
        return {
          [`page${index + 1}`]: page?.items,
        };
      }),
      totalPages: data?.pages?.[0].pagination?.totalPages,
    };
  }

  return {
    data: watchlistResultsDTO,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    isSuccess,
    hasNextPage,
    hasPreviousPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    fetchPreviousPage,
    refetch,
    isRefetching,
  };
   }
```

Mutate Hook:

```
  const { isLoading: isLoadingRemovingContent, mutate: removeContent } =
    useMutation({
      mutationFn: ({ userId, contentId }) =>
        removeFromUserWatchlist(userId, contentId),
      onSuccess: () => {

        queryClient.cancelQueries({
          queryKey: ['watchlist', userId],
          exact: true,
          refetchActive: false,
          refetchInactive: false,
        });

        queryClient.refetchQueries(['watchlist', userId], {
          exact: true,
          active: true,
          inactive: true,
        });

    console.log(
      'query data: ',
      queryClient.getQueryData(['watchlist', userId])
    );

        onContentRemoved && onContentRemoved();
      },
    });
```

Después de eliminar, puedes ver que cancelo las consultas y luego las vuelvo a obtener. Cuando imprimo en la consola los datos en OnSuccess (el gancho de mutación), puedo ver que los pageParams son: [undefined, 2, 3, 4]. Pero la función de consulta (queryFn) del gancho de Infinito siempre comienza una página antes de la última y realiza las solicitudes de las páginas 3, 4, 5. No sé por qué tengo este comportamiento. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme o darme alguna idea sobre este problema?

Comment: Este es StackOverflow **en español**. Aquí escribimos en la lengua de Cervantes. Si quieres publicar en inglés, puedes ir al sitio correspondiente: [SO], o puedes [edit] tu pregunta y publicarla en nuestro idioma. Por ahora, me temo que será cerrada por la comunidad por esta misma razón. Un saludo.